# Create a custom filter

Tags: views

i would like to create a filter in order to only display artist who have Lips focused in the third column. (I don't want an exposed filter).
In this case i would like to only display artist2 , laradelvaux and bdash01

Another example: if the fourth column contains Nude Look, then only bdash01 will be display.

The fourth column is dynamic. The values can be: Contouring & Brows or Eyes Focused or Lips Focused or Natural Look or...

I tried many modules with no success:

[Views Reference Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_filter), [Views Dependent Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_dependent_filters), [Views Selective Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_selective_filters), [Views Filter Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_filterfield), [Views Global Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/global_filter) and many others.

(I'm not friendly with PHP).

[image]

I tried to use Views PHP
with this custom filter (screenshot) but it does not work.

[image]